# Working with Redux Dev Tools extension and Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I'm converting my project to Typescript.

This has always worked for me in JS.

```
/* ##################### */
/* #### REDUX STORE #### */
/* ##################### */

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {
  // INITIAL STATE GOES HERE
},window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
```

But in Typescript I'm getting these errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is getting throw from the TS compiler because it doesn't know about **REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** property on the Window object. You can extend the Window interface and add that which will make the TS compiler happy. Or you can do this:

```
createStore(rootReducer,{//INITIAL STATE GOES HERE},composeWithDevTools());
```

cite: https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store#integrating-the-devtools-extension

Comment: Thanks! Can I leave this on for production? Or should I bother removing it?

Comment: That probably depends on if you have a consumer-facing app or not, if you're storing secrets in state, etc? I don't personally think it's a big deal but YMMV. Here's what I found just from a quick google search: https://medium.com/@zalmoxis/using-redux-devtools-in-production-4c5b56c5600f and here's how to exclude them if you want - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md#exclude-devtools-from-production-builds

Comment: Even better, you should use [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which has a `configureStore` function that automatically enables the Redux DevTools Extension for you.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest solution i found is to explicitly add `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` to the window object

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
  __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}
```